# How to fix Ubuntu Server not booting?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

What I meant from the title is that after I install ubuntu server, the computer will not detect the drive as bootable, and I used rufus to make it a MBR USB Installer, and when I check the hard drive in my main PC, It shows the Drive as GPT and that it has an unallocated partition, and I made sure that the Drive was formatted as MBR before the entire procedure.

Note: The PC can only boot off an MBR Drive.
The Version of Ubuntu server is 18.04 LTS I believe and it's a live installer.

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: More details may help, what release of Ubuntu Server (18.04 LTS, 19.04, 19.10 etc) and what media (standard installer, live installer, network installer etc) as currently you've said you installed 1 of the 12+ options and need help.  Did you verify download of ISO before write?  did you verify write to install media? (one downloads may not allow for this..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by checking your bios setting. Once i stucked on the same problem and that was solved by unchecking HDD array setting on my BIOS. And the application you are using to make bootable usb drive works the best. So there would must be problem in BIOS boot setting.